# Make SQL recognize a variable from PHP/html selected option

Tags: php, sql

I think the answer to this may be simple, but being new to SQL I am still growing. Here's my dilemma. I have a php array of options with 10 values. When any one option is selected it is passed into a variable named "spots". I have 10 SQL SELECT statements that pull 1 of 10 different tables. The issue is that I do not know exactly what to do in order to get the SQL to recognize which value was selected and based on which was selected show that specific table data.  (This would be easy if I were able to use the JavaScript Switch statement, but I do not know an equivalent for that)

EXAMPLE:

PHP

```
$spots = ["Report1","Report2","Report3","Report4","Report5","Report6","Report7","Report8","Report9","Report10"];
```

SQL

```
SELECT *, FROM Report5
ORDER BY TW ASC;
```

Now how do I get SQL to loop through an array to find a match, then depending on that match select from a list of commands (for example like a JavaScript switch statement)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use variable substitution:

```
foreach ($spots as $spot) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $spot ORDER BY TW ASC";
    // perform the SQL query using $sql, do what you want with the results
}
```

Make sure you've validated that the values in `$spots` are valid if they're coming from the user. Otherwise you'll be subjecting your code to SQL injection.